# Android App Vs Widget. Advantages and disadvantages

Tags: android

Greetings,

What are advantages and disadvantages of a widget over an app?

I would like to compare the following perspectives:

1. developer: What's easier to develop? to maintain? which is more powerful?
2. user: what easier to use? integrates better? takes less resources?

Thank you

Comment: They are completely different things, one appears on a home screen and one is a series of activities. You don't choose one because it's easier or more efficient, you choose one because it is the required interface.

Comment: I know, still I would like to do a comparison

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is little old but I am still adding this comments for the benefit of others who might see it later...
Refer to following link for more info on advantages and disadvantages of Widgets in mobile phone:

http://www.ehow.com/info_10004977_disadvantages-using-widgets.html

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Moreover this doesnt answer the complete question. Try to provide answers more appropriate to the entire question instead of partially answering it.